# How to find the second largest integer in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I have to return an integer that is the second highest integer in an ArrayList. A parameter in the method is `arr` which is an ArrayList. The code below does not work for some instances. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
int largest = arr.get(0);
int secondLarg;

if(arr.get(0) < arr.get(1)) {
    largest = arr.get(1);
    secondLarg = arr.get(0);
}
else {
    secondLarg = arr.get(1);
}

for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    if(arr.get(i) >= largest) {
        largest = arr.get(i);
    }
    else if(arr.get(i) < largest && arr.get(i) >= secondLarg) {
        secondLarg = arr.get(i);
    }
}

return secondLarg;
```

Comment: What's an example of an array that doesn't work?

Comment: The website that I am using does not allow me to see the array that it uses to check my code.

Comment: What happens if the next array entry you read is > largest?  What information do you lose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if(arr.get(i) >= largest) {
>     largest = arr.get(i);
> }
> ```

If the new item is the largest then `largest` needs to point to the new item and **`secondLarg` needs to point to the previous `largest`**.